# How to facet by requestUri with parameter exclusion

Tags: newrelic

Let's say that I have a query:
`SELECT count(*) from Transaction where appName='applicationName' and requestUri like '/deviceId/%' and httpResponseCode = '404' LIMIT max FACET requestUri`
where `%` is a placeholder for deviceId number as a endpoint parameter.

Now the result of the New Relic query is the list of metrics:

`/deviceId/id1` with number of occurrences,

`/deviceId/id2` with number of occurrences,

`/deviceId/id3` with number of occurrences

All I want to achieve is receiving results with the number of endpoint occurrences but without distinguishing it by endpoint param like below:
`/deviceId/%` 3 occurrences.

I've searched the Internet, but most examples involve faceting the entire `requestUri`, which in my case forces manual counting of all endpoint calls.

I will be grateful for suggestions on how to fix the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply regex `RLIKE` to facet your data, for example:

`SELECT count(*) FROM Transaction WHERE hostname RLIKE 'ip-10-351-[0-2]?[0-9]-.*'`

For more details and documentation, follow this url:
https://docs.newrelic.com/whats-new/2021/04/nrql-updates/

Answer (score 0):

To get all occurrences for 1 endpoint you dont need to use *FACET* here, just *COUNT()*. *FACET* is used to split by some aspect (exactly what you see in your result)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Transaction 
WHERE appName='applicationName' 
   AND requestUri like '/deviceId/%' 
   AND httpResponseCode = '404' 
LIMIT MAX
```

As a result, you receive 1 number which is all occurrences for all */deviceId/%*

[Example of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q67C9.png)

But be aware, that it counts also endpoints like */deviceId/{ID}/some/info*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` in your `facet` operation.

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
from Transaction
where appName='applicationName' and httpResponseCode = '404'
LIMIT max
FACET CASE(WHERE requestUri like '/deviceId/%' as device_path)
```

you can also include more options on `CASE`.

```
SELECT count(*)
from Transaction where appName='applicationName' and httpResponseCode = '404'
LIMIT max
FACET CASE(
  WHERE requestUri like '/deviceId/%' as device_path,
  WHERE requestUri LIKE '/something/%' as something_path
)
```